# Rails N + 1 query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following Rails code:

Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @orders = current_hotel.restaurant_orders
  end
end
```

View:

```
json.array! @orders do |order|
  json.id order.id
  json.room order.room
  json.note order.note
  json.order_status_id order.order_status_id
  json.created_at order.created_at
  json.total_cost   order.total_cost

  json.restaurant_order_items order.restaurant_order_items do |roi|
    json.id roi.id
    json.count roi.count
    json.cost roi.cost
    json.title roi.title
    json.total_cost roi.total_cost
  end

  json.restaurant do
    json.id order.restaurant.id
    json.email order.restaurant.email
    json.phone order.restaurant.phone

    json.place { json.title order.restaurant.place.title }
  end
end
```

If I understand right Rails will make 1 + 2 * N requests. How can I make it faster? Should I add 'includes' to it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the simple use of eager-loading shall do the task

Comment: If you want to know for sure how many queries will be executed, you can check the console output. I'm not sure this will result in 1 + 2N queries.

For what it's worth, if you want to automatically include all order items you can do `current_hotel.restaurant_orders.includes(:restaurant_order_items)`

Comment: Why not? 1 query for getting all orders, N for getting restaurant_order_items for each order and N for getting restaurant for each order. How can I look at this algorithm in console? Thanks

Comment: When you run rails server and go to the website, the SQL queries are logged in the terminal where you started the server.